# Exclude patterns from glob match

Tags: bash, wildcards, pattern-matching

My directory looks like this:

```
$ ls
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 18 22:44 file0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 18 22:44 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 18 22:44 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 18 22:44 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 18 22:44 file4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 18 22:44 file5
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 18 22:44 file6
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 18 22:44 file7
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 18 22:44 file8
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 18 22:44 file9
```

Using bash globbing, I want to match `file2` to `file6`, *excluding* `file3`.

Since I could not find an `and` operator for matching multiple patterns, I figured I just use DeMorgan's law that `a AND b` is equivalent to `!(!a OR !b)` and write

```
!(!(file[2-6])|file3)
```

which works as expected:

```
$ echo !(!(file[2-6])|file3)
file2 file4 file5 file6
```

Is there an easier, more direct way to achieve this?

Comment: Does the real life issue on your system also include removing a single name from a set of matching names in a short numerical range, like in your question, or is the actual situation more complex?

Comment: @Kusalananda I am looking for a solution that works for the _abstract_ problem of matching everything that matches `pattern1` but not `pattern2`.

Comment: That makes your example rather deceptive as it's easy to leave out `4` from `file[23456]`. You may want to update your question with a further explanation of the general issue so that people here don't think you're interested in the specific example you are showing (which is now the case).

Answer (score 4):

You can apply two ranges `[24-6]`, where `2` is the first and `4-6` is the second:

```bash
$ ls file[24-6]
file2 file4 file5 file6
```

Another example:

```bash
$ ls file[2356]
file2 file3 file5 file6
```

[Documentation:](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)

> ##### Ranges
>
> There is one special convention: two characters separated by '-'
> denote a range.  (Thus, "[A-Fa-f0-9]" is equivalent to
> "[ABCDEFabcdef0123456789]".)  One may include '-' in its literal
> meaning by making it the first or last character between the
> brackets.  (Thus, "[]-]" matches just the two characters ']' and
> '-', and "[--0]" matches the three characters '-', '.', '0',
> since '/' cannot be matched.)

Answer (score 4):

negate range :

```
printf '%s\n' file[!013789]
```

[As stated here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) :

> If the first character following the ‘[’ is a ‘!’ or a ‘^’ then any character not enclosed is matched.

---

setting `GLOBIGNORE` to the file you want to skip:

```
GLOBIGNORE="file0:file1:file3:file7:file8:file9"
printf '%s\n' file*
```

[see this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)  :

> The GLOBIGNORE shell variable may be used to restrict the set of file names matching a pattern. If GLOBIGNORE is set, each matching file name that also matches one of the patterns in GLOBIGNORE is removed from the list of matches.

---

Using `extended globbing`:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' file!([013789])
```

[see extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)